# Index was outside the bounds of the array c#

Tags: c#

I get the error of "Index was outside the bounds of the array", at this line " order.price = Convert.ToDouble(custOrder.Split('$')[1]); ", I have follow the video at here, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbrGoUqbb-A, but I still get the error, I am newbie for C#

```
 public struct Orders
            {
                public string item;
                public double price;

            }

            const double TAX=0.06;
            Orders order = new Orders();
            static double subtotal=0;
            static double totalTaxes=0;  
            static double total;
            string finalBill = "FINAL BILL:\n";
     private void getValues(string custOrder)
            {

                order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];

                order.price = Convert.ToDouble(custOrder.Split('$')[1]);    
                listOutput.Items.Add("Price:" + order.price);

                finalBill += "Ordered Item:" + order.item + "\nPrice:" + order.price.ToString("C2") + "\n";
                updateBill();

            }

            private void updateBill()
            {
                subtotal += order.price;
                total += order.price + (order.price * TAX);
                totalTaxes += order.price * TAX;
                listOutput.Items.Clear();
                listOutput.Items.Add(finalBill);
                listOutput.Items.Add("Subtotal:" + subtotal.ToString("C2"));
                listOutput.Items.Add("Tax:" + totalTaxes.ToString("C2"));
                listOutput.Items.Add("Total:" + total.ToString("C2"));

            }
            private void dropdownSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (sender == comboBox1)
                    getValues(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

            }
```

Comment: It's likely the string doesn't contain a $ sign, or there isn't anything after it. Verify your input string

Comment: What's the value of comboBox1.SelectedItem ?

Comment: Better to post your HTML also, specially comboBox1

Comment: my input string is like: chair $5

Comment: my dataTable is "itemInfo", data column of the item name & price is :"ItemName", I have edit the " order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];" according to my detail, but seem does not work. Where is the problem?

Comment: how you fill combobox?

Comment: yes...the data at comboBox is load from the database

Comment: try call `getValues("chair $5")` are you get same error?

Answer (score 0):

```
custOrder.Split('$')[1]
```

Stuff that into a variable and use your debugger.  Looks like your string `custOrder` does not contain a `'$'` character, or it is the last character in the string.

Comment: my data is like: chair $5

Comment: my dataTable is "itemInfo", data column of the item name & price is :"ItemName", I have edit the " order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];" according to my detail, but seem does not work. Where is the problem?

Comment: @user4562396: http://ideone.com/CoA5w7  The problem is in your input, which we can't see.  Seriously, this is a very simple fix if you just use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

your string does not contain the '$' text or it only contains 1 of them.  try this instead:

```
string[] splits = custOrder.Split("$".ToCharArray());

if (1 == splits.Length)
    order.item = Convert.ToDouble(splits[0]);
else
   throw new Exception("Cannot find $ in the customer order");
```

Depending on what you want you also may have meant Convert.ToDouble(splits[0]); as arrays use zero based indexing not 1 based indexing.

EDIT: changed code based on questioner providing input data sample.

Comment: my data is like: chair $5

Comment: my dataTable is "itemInfo", data column of the item name & price is :"ItemName", I have edit the " order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];" according to my detail, but seem does not work. Where is the problem?

Comment: @user4562396 I really need more information than it doesn't work, in order to help you.   What specifically is the behavior.

Comment: does the naming for my data table & info correct? i wish to post the pic of my table, but my reputation is not enough, i just can describe using word. Databse:data.mdf; Table: itemInfo; Column:Item_Id, ItemName, ItemPrice, ItemDescription; ItemName data: table $10, chair &5...etc, the naming at "itemInfo.ItemName = custOrder.Split('$')[0];" is that correct?

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[itemInfo] ([Item_Id], [ItemName], [ItemPrice], [ItemDescription]) VALUES (1, N'table$10  ', CAST(10.0000 AS Money), NULL)

Answer (score 0):

the .Split method, when used on a string, it returns an array. The split parameter is a character that is used as the splitting point.

For example:

```
String x = "test$one";
var result = x.Split('$') // this returns an array ["test", "one"]
```

the arrays start their counting from zero, so

```
result[0] // is "test"
result[1] // is "one"
```

the splitting character is not included.

In your case, there is no dollar sign, so the split result will be an array with just one string, with the index 0. `custOrder.Split('$')[1]` does not exist.

Comment: my data is like: chair $5

Comment: Then you should break the action into two steps, first execute the split, then in another line do the conversion. This way you can add a breakpoint and check the values of the split's array, or use Console.log to print them out.

Comment: my dataTable is "itemInfo", data column of the item name & price is :"ItemName", I have edit the " order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];" according to my detail, but seem does not work. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update your getValue method as follows
Check whether you split call really returns 2 array elements to get element of index=1.
Also check whether the returned value of index=1 is really of type double or not. else you will get another error for the string like "asdf$gf" or "asdf$"

```
        private void getValues(string custOrder)
        {
            double num;
            if (custOrder.Split('$').Count() > 1)
            {
                order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];
               if (double.TryParse(custOrder.Split('$')[1], out num))
                { 
                    order.price = Convert.ToDouble(custOrder.Split('$')[1]);                     
                    listOutput.Items.Add("Price:" + order.price);
                    finalBill += "Ordered Item:" + order.item + "\nPrice:" + order.price.ToString("C2") + "\n";
                    updateBill();
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: it return me the error "Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out double)' has some invalid arguments"  Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'

Comment: my dataTable is "itemInfo", data column of the item name & price is :"ItemName", I have edit the " order.item = custOrder.Split('$')[0];" according to my detail, but seem does not work. Where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry. had to change the if statement above and there is a slight change made in the condition